# ASP.NET MVC 2 app pool crashes - how to debug on server?

Tags: debugging, asp.net-mvc-2, crash, application-pool

My application which was built in asp.net mvc 2 crashes sometimes (maybe once a month), and the error is **Service Unavailable 503**. Both times restarting app pool made the application work again. Since this error only happens live on the server (shared hosting) I don't know how to debug it. I don't have access to event logs so I don't see a way for debugging it.
 Any suggestion?

UPDATE:
I contacted my hosting provider and they sent me this:

> **Imposed memory limit in Windows servers** 
>   Q: Is there a CPU/memory limit/restriction for Windows
>   Plans? A: Yes. 100MB for Reseller Class, 250MB for Personal Class ASP
>   and 500MB for Business Class ASP.
>
> Q: What will happen if I hit the memory limit? A: If the worker
>   process exceeds the private memory quota, IIS will recycle that pool
>   which limits the memory usage. Your active sessions to the website may
>   get expired. If your site works on authentication you will be asked to
>   login again.
>
> Q: How can I check the memory limit for my site? A: Run your site in
>   your local or test machine with the limits and try to optimize the
>   codes. If the limit of 250MB is exceeded you should get Business
>   Class, else you can go for Personal Class.
>
> Q: What if my site exceeds the 500MB limit in Business Class? A: We
>   can increase the worker process to 2 if you are in a Business Class
>   server. If the number of worker processes are increased, the load will
>   be evenly shared across both the WP processes.
>
> If the memory usage is still high, you should consider getting a
>   dedicated server where you can use unmetered memory for your website.

My account is Personal Class ASP (250MB). Since [my website](http://ilijaveselica.com) is a photo gallery, could this be related with generating thumbnails?

Thanks,
Ilija

Answer (score 1):

Are you generating thumbnails on the fly when the request for thumbnail comes to the server? If yes, then you might want to consider generating thumbnails when you *upload* the photo and then just serve smaller images.

Very nice pictures, btw ;-)

PS. Try setting up memory limit on your local machine and hammer it with multiple requests - maybe you will be able to reproduce it.

Comment: I generate only those small thumbnails on home page. For example: http://ilijaveselica.com/Home/ShowCroppedImage/440?size=42. Thanks ;)